# left outer join on nullable field with between in join condition (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, left-join, between

I have two tables as: `table1` with fields `c1` and `dt`(nullable); `table2` with fields `start_dt`, `end_dt` and `wk_id`. Now I need to perform left outer join between the `table1` and `table2` to take `wk_id` such that `dt` falls between `start_dt` and `end_dt`. I applied following condition but some `wk_id` which shouldn't be `NULL` are pulled `NULL` and some rows get repeated.

```
where nvl(t1.dt,'x') between nvl(t2.start_dt(+), 'x') and nvl(t2.end_dt(+), 'x');
```

What is wrong with the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
    on t1.dt between t2.start_dt and t2.end_dt
```

I recommend you try the new ANSI join syntax.

Also, are you just using `'x'` as an example?  Or are the `dt` columns really stored as strings?

Comment: `dt` fields are `DATE` and I am using `x` as any character to match when `dt` is `NULL`. `x` could be anything but it should be the same on both sides.

Comment: I'm surprised your implicit conversion works.  Maybe that's a version difference, but on 11.2.0.3, Oracle tries to convert the 'x' into a date, which always fails with `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`.  (And as far as I know, there is no NLS_DATE_FROMAT that will work with "x".)  I suspect you don't need to use `NVL` anyway, but if you do, then
it's much safer to use a date literal, such as `date '1000-01-01'`.  As for the join, if you can post some examples I'm sure someone can figure out exactly how to make it work.

Comment: As you said, `x` should be some date. And I can't go for ANSI join because in my main query, there are some other dynamic joins which have to be written in old style. So, my main concern was to perform outer join on `dt between start_dt and end_dt` in old style. I figured out that simply `where t1.dt between t2.start_dt(+) and t2.end_dt(+)` works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the part "**table1 left outer join table2 on table1.some_field = table2.some_field**"

Something like this:

```
select t1.c1, t1.dt, t2.start_dt, t2.end_dt, t2.wk_id
from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2
on t1.some_field1 = t2.some_field1
where nvl(t1.dt,'x') 
between nvl(t2.start_dt, 'x') and 
nvl(t2.end_dt, 'x')
```

Comment: I don't have that `some_field1` to perform join. If I had such field I could simply write `where nvl(t1.some_field1,'x') = nvl(t2.some_field1(+), 'x');` Data uniqueness is maintained by the combination of `start_dt` and `end_dt` in `table2` which makes the situation a bit odd.